# Get current user in djangocms plugins (CMSPluginBase)

Tags: django, django-cms

I want to create a plugin whose content is different depending on the user who opens the page.
I tried :

```py
@plugin_pool.register_plugin  # register the plugin
class RubriquePluginPublisher(CMSPluginBase):
    """
    RubriquePluginPublisher : CMSPluginBase
    """
    model = RubriquePluginModel  # model where plugin data are saved
    module = "Rubrique"
    name = "Rubrique plugin"  # name of the plugin in the interface
    render_template = "commission/rubrique_plugin.html"

    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context.update({'instance': instance})
        query_set = Article.objects.filter(rubriques=instance.rubrique).filter(contact=self.request.user)
        page = context['request'].GET.get('page_{}'.format(instance.rubrique.name)) or 1
        paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(page, query_set, 3)
        context.update({'paginator': paginator,
                        'page_obj': page,
                        'is_paginated': is_paginated,
                        'articles': queryset
                        })
        return context
```

But self.request doesn't exist in class CMSPluginBase.
How can I access the current user?

EDIT :
I found a workaround. I created a middleware that returns the current request. It works well but don't hesitate if someone has a better solution.

```py
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

_requests = {}

def get_current_request():
    t = current_thread()
    if t not in _requests:
         return None
    return _requests[t]

class RequestMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        _requests[current_thread()] = request
```

```py
@plugin_pool.register_plugin  # register the plugin
class PrivateRubriquePluginPublisher(CMSPluginBase):
    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        req = get_current_request()
        query_set = Article.objects.filter(contact=req.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the recommended approach would be:

1. Add `django.template.context_processors.request` to your `context_processors` in settings.py - this will add a `request` variable to your context.
2. Then in `CMSPluginBase.render` you could access it as following:

```py
    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super().render(context, instance, placeholder)
        request: HttpRequest = context['request']
```